# Are there any limits to the number of domains one can add when doing an advanced Google Search?

Tags: google-search

I am trying to find out if there is a limit to the number of domains I can add on advanced Google Search.
For example, if I want my search results limited to particular websites, I can add some domains to my search and my search results will only come from the selected domains. 
Is there a limit to the number of domains I can add?

[image]

[google adv search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search?q=london%20bridge%20attack&rlz=1C1GCEA_enGB871GB871&sxsrf=ACYBGNSxr6zKC3L3-t3SKwpznCqX8aRgag:1575294713478&hl=en)

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "xxxx **(and any subsequent words) was ignored because we limit queries to 32 words**."

You can read more about all limits imposed by Google at [Specifications and Usage Limits](https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/4411411#requests)